# why my running section showing "AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'load'" even though I didn't write "load"?

Tags: python

Code:

```
canvas = np.ones((800, 780, 3), dtype="uint8")
canvas.fill(255)
l_img = canvas


text = 'love'

font_path = "CotrellCFExtraBold-ExtraBold.ttf"
font = ImageFont.truetype(font_path, 192)

imgPil = Image.fromarray(l_img)
ImageDraw.Draw(l_img).text((30, 30),  text, font = font, fill = (0, 0, 0))
img = np.array(l_img)
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\daphn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageDraw.py", line 465, in Draw
    return im.getdraw(mode)
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'getdraw'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/daphn/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/homework/05poster.b.py", line 153, in <module>
    ImageDraw.Draw(l_img).text((30, 30),  text, font = font, fill = (0, 0, 0))
  File "C:\Users\daphn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageDraw.py", line 467, in Draw
    return ImageDraw(im, mode)
  File "C:\Users\daphn\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageDraw.py", line 59, in __init__
    im.load()
**AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'load'**

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Don't know why it shows 'AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'load''(solved now)
But the words still didn't show up.

Comment: Shouldn't the code `ImageDraw.Draw(l_img)` actually be `ImageDraw.Draw(imgPil)`? It's hard to say without seeing the definition of `l_img`, though, so I recommend posting a [mre].

Comment: Knowing where `l_img` is coming from seems important. Please extend the code snippet to include at least that.

Comment: @RandomDavis Oh! I see it now! Thank you so much!

Comment: canvas = np.ones((800, 780, 3), dtype="uint8")
canvas.fill(255)

Comment: 'l_img = canvas'

Comment: @user14939907 please put code in your post, never in comments.

Comment: @RandomDavis sorry, new here. A bit confused about what should put where...

Comment: @RandomDavis I apologize for bothering you, but may I ask why the words didn't show up when there seems no problems and the code has been finished?

Comment: @user14939907 what words? Show up where? Are you drawing the image anywhere via code? Or saving it? If you aren't doing either of those, then where are you expecting to see the change?

Comment: Ohhhhhhh! Wait! I get it now!!!!!!!!!! the name! it called "img" now!

Comment: @RandomDavisTHANK YOU SO MUCH! I WAS SO LOST ON THAT TINY MISTAKE! THANK YOU FOR THE COMMENT!

Answer (score 0):

```
canvas = np.ones((800, 780, 3), dtype="uint8")
canvas.fill(255)
l_img = canvas


text = 'love'
font_path = "CotrellCFExtraBold-ExtraBold.ttf"
font = ImageFont.truetype(font_path, 192)

imgPil = Image.fromarray(l_img)
ImageDraw.Draw(imgPil).text((50, 50),  text, font = font, fill = (0, 0, 0))
img = np.array(imgPil)

cv2.imshow('a', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I wrote"cv2.imshow('a', img_l)", but is had changed at the "imgPil = Image.fromarray(l_img)", and then it changed again at "img = np.array(imgPil)"!